# Spring boot properties vs maven pom packaging tag

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml, spring-properties

I have been facing some problems with spring boot and maven.

It seems that the `<packaging>pom</packaging>` tag, when added to `pom.xml`, somehow makes spring completely unaware of the parent-level `applications.properties` configuration file. When running, spring still will show the banner and info-level logging regardless of the properties stated.  Why would that be the case? Is there a way to add those properties to my parent such that all modules would operate under given configuration? Would this become an anti-pattern?

Main class:

```java
package com.example.app; //could also be inside the app-client module

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
logging.level.root=info
```

(parent) pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>app-client</module>
    </modules>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>app</name>
    <description>Demo app</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Why have you added `<packaging>pom</packaging>` to what looks like a module that will produce a jar file containing a Spring Boot-based application?

Comment: The project is beginning to take shape, so this is the first attempt to add one of many future modules to it. The ideia is to have a pom-packaging parent and jar-packaging children modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally agreeing with the comment of Andy on your question I like to point out, that the use of the `packaging` type `pom` is appropriate if you want to denote an artifact as some kind of module container are base project where you collect dependency information for your (sub-)modules.

However the `@SpringBootApplication` in your case shows us that you want to use your artifact for running business code. That on the other hand leads to `packaging` types like `jar` or `war`. Switch it to one of them and everything should run fine.

> For more information please consult also the [Maven reference for packaging](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates).

Comment: Doing some research and it seems like my maven modules folder structure was also badly structured. I have kept the pom packaging for the parent, added some child (or sub) modules, moved `Main` and `application.properties` to one of them and now the properties are working again. Jar-packaging inside child modules, and pom-packaging for the parent worked for me.

Comment: @EvandroTeixeira I have built the same structore (parent->pom, child module ->jar), but I am getting data-source related error, meaning application.yml isn't loading?

Comment: @aleksaRazer22 It's been a long time since I've touched that project. All I can remember was that the parent pom had no source code directly associated with it, only modules, each with it's own source and `pom.xml`, including the one where Main is situated. The rule of thumb for me it's to look at any popular java/kotlin maven-based spring project and copy their pom structure.